# get all truthy values in an array within a given limit

Tags: ruby

I want to get all truthy values in an array (in this example that would be numeric values). But once the limit has been reached I do not want to continue looking for truthy values. My initial thought was to do this:

```
a.select do |n|
  puts "value #{n}"
  n.is_a? Numeric
end.slice(0..9)

value 1
value 2
value 3
value 4
value 5
value 6
value 7
value 8
value 9
value 10
value 11
value 12
value 13
value 14
value 15
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

While it gives me the correct results, it still searches through every record. I want it to stop searching when I hit the limit.

How can I achieve this in Ruby?

Comment: it is the input array @sagarpandya82

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved with [`lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy) and [`first`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-first) - both methods are defined on [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html):

```
(1..20).lazy.select do |n|
  puts "value #{n}"
  n.is_a? Numeric
end.first(10)
#=> value 1
#=> value 2
#=> value 3
#=> value 4
#=> value 5
#=> value 6
#=> value 7
#=> value 8
#=> value 9
#=> value 10
#=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: `lazy.select(&:itself).first(10)` for first 10 truthy values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#take_while`

```
limit = 9
result = []
a.take_while do |i| 
  result << i if i
  result.length - 1 < limit
end
```

In Ruby every object is *truthy* except `nil` and `false`. So truthy check is being made by `if i` like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use until or while

```
b = []
i = 0
until i > 10 || i = a.length
  if a[i].is_a? Numeric
    b << a[i]
    i += 1
  end
end
```